# Build error in android opencv project?

Tags: android, c++, opencv

When i tried to compile a sample program come with opencv for android sdk, i have the following error, I am new in this area, any idea how can i fix them?

E:\software\androidndk\ndk-build.cmd all 
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk
E:/software/androidndk/build/core/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
E:/software/androidndk/build/core/add-application.mk:165: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

Comment: does anyone can get my question answer well? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have solved the problem myself, 
i have unchecked the "is library option" in project properties during running my project also in android.mk i have added following line

```
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
```